# Properly Formatting "For Each" to be used with JSON

Tags: json, for-loop

I am coding in VB.NET. I need help reading a JSON. Here is the raw JSON data:

```js
{
  "status": 200,
  "likelihood": 2,
  "data": {
    "emails": [
      {
        "address": "none@hotmail.com",
        "type": "personal",
        "sha256": "53ec4387bf9f1e3ff62458000d3203518d1ed08d8de49bdd3493099befed7822",
        "domain": "hotmail.com",
        "local": "none"
      }
    ],
```

Okay, now in order for me to read the emails array I need to do this:

```
        Dim read = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(GlobalVariables.MostRecentSearch)
        For Each read.Item("data")("emails") As string
            TextBox4.Text = read.Item("data")("emails")(0)("address").ToString
        Next
```

But obviously my For Each statement is wrong. In the code above where the index is shown as (0) and I want to cycle through all of the potential email addresses (of unknown count), how do I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Here is the correct formatting of the For Each statement:

```
                Dim emails As String
                emails = ""
                For Each email As Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject In read.Item("data")("emails")
                    emails = emails & email.Item("address").ToString & ","
                Next
```